# Erro ao converter String para Números em Java

Tags: java, string, scanner, number-format

No meu último post ([do/while repete duas vezes a expressão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268952/do-while-repete-duas-vezes-a-express%C3%A3o?noredirect=1#comment551049_268952)) estava com um problema de sobreposição de entradas usando a classe Scanner, e conforme os links colocados na resposta, não podemos usar o nextLine() depois do nextInt().

Agora estou fazendo outro algoritmo e cai no mesmo problema. Conforme solução do link usado como resposta, usei o Integer.parseInt() para resolver o problema. Ocorre que agora está ocorrendo o erro java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Pelo que entendi pesquisando em inglês é porque a String está vazia. Ok, está mesmo. Porém é porque ele retorna o erro antes mesmo que eu possa digitar, sendo que tem uma linha antes pedindo a entrada de um valor na String.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Como podem ver na imagem acima, após eu inserir a terceira nota ele já dá o erro, antes que eu coloque a frequência.*

**Segue o código:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    String matricula;
    String resultado;
    String frequencia = "0";
    int freq;
    double nota1, nota2, nota3, notaFinal;
    double maiorNota;
    double menorNota;
    double mediaGeral = 0;
    int totalRep = 0;
    double percentRepFreq;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

        System.out.print("Entre com a matrícula do aluno " + i + ": ");
        matricula = read.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Digite as 3 notas do aluno " + i + "\nNota 1: ");
        nota1 = read.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Nota 2: ");
        nota2 = read.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Nota 3: ");
        nota3 = read.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Digite a frequência do aluno " + i + ": ");
        frequencia = read.nextLine();

        freq = Integer.parseInt(frequencia);
        if (freq < 40) {
            totalRep += 1;
        }

        notaFinal = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3;
        mediaGeral += notaFinal;

        if (notaFinal >= 6 && freq >= 40) {
            resultado = "Aprovado.";
        } else {
            resultado = "Reprovado.";
        }

        System.out.println("Aluno " + i + ", com matrícula " + matricula + ", teve frequência de " + frequencia
                + ", nota final: " + notaFinal + " e foi " + resultado);

        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    percentRepFreq = (int) totalRep / 5 * 100;

    System.out.println("Media geral da turma: " + mediaGeral);
    System.out.println("Total de alunos reprovados: " + totalRep);
    System.out.println(percentRepFreq + "% " + "dos alunos foram reprovados por frequência.");

}
```

}

Comment: Veja [esta sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268952/do-while-repete-duas-vezes-a-express%C3%A3o#comment551049_268952) e todas as marcadas como duplicadas **atentamente**. O problema é o mesmo. o `parseInt` que colocou não muda nada pois continua a ter `nextDouble` seguido de `nextLine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use next(); invez de nextLine() na hora de pegar frequencia

```
frequencia = read.next();
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece por que `nextDouble()` (ou `nextInt()`, `nextFloat()` e etc) não funcionam da mesma forma que o `nextLine()`.

O `nextLine()` resgata a próxima linha do seu input, já `nextDouble()` resgata o próximo `double` do seu input, sendo que esse não precisa, necessariamente, ser todo o conteúdo da linha.

Por exemplo: se na criação da instância de `Scanner` você fizer:

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(" ");
```

E na execução, no momento de informar a primeira nota, ao invés de passar um único valor, passar três valores separados por espaço (ex: `1 2 3` (tem um último espaço depois do `3`)), a captura das notas 2 e 3 irá ocorrer de forma *automagica* justamente pelo fato de esses métodos não lerem a linha inteira mas só o *próximo `Double`*.

---

Para solucionar o problema existem, basicamente, duas opções:

- Chamar o método `nextLine()` depois de cada chamada de `nextDouble()`
- Ou alterar de `nextDouble()` para `nextLine()` e fazer as conversões "na mão" (algo como `Double.parseDouble(val)`)

Comment: Agora estou entendo melhor, juro que li os outros posts, mas achei que era só com int o problema. Muito obrigado! Mas só para ficar 100% claro então: não importa a ordem se vem o nextDouble ou Line primeiro, é isso? 

Ps: quero aprofundar e entender melhor, mas marquei a resposta do kervincandido porque funcionou perfeitamente substituindo os dois nextLine pelo next e foi bem prático.

Comment: @LuisFernando a ordem importa sim... Se você quiser usar o `nextDouble()` vc precisará chamar o `nextLine()` em seguida. Particularmente, **eu** acho melhor você usar só o `nextLine()` e garantir a conversão no código.. Até pq o usuário pode digitar `8,5` ao invés de `8.5` e o código irá quebrar, saca?

Comment: @LuisFernando a resposta que você marcou resolve parcialmente seu problema. Na verdade, ela esconde seu problema. Não o resolve nem explica o porque o código se comporta dessa forma. Por mim, não tem problema algum não marcar a minha resposta como correta, só acho que a que está marcada atualmente não resolve seu problema... Se for seguir a logica da resposta você nunca poderá usar o `nextLine()`, certo?

Comment: Certo, realmente nunca poderia, mas como esse código é simples não tive necessidade de usar o nextline, resolveu. Acho que é uma das soluções possíveis, pelo menos para códigos mais simples. Agora pode ser necessário em outro código ou situação eu ter que usar o nextline e por isso aprofundei na pergunta. Mas de fato, relendo agora, vejo que com essas suas respostas aprendi bem mais, inclusive não tinha pensado nessa questão da ",". Agora sim entendi. Valeu pela disposição.